# Unique min and max in partially ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Given a partial order $\prec$ on a non-empty set $A$ and a set $B$, which is a non-empty subset of $A$, I have to prove, that $min B$ is unique (provided it exists).

My problem understanding this, is the following:
Let's say:
$A=\mathcal{P}(\{a,b\})=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ and
$\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}=B\subseteq A$
$X\prec Y :\Leftrightarrow X\subseteq Y$
The requirements of the problem are satisfied, but $min B$ is not unique, or am I missing something?

I have no problem solving it for a total order, but I don't get how uniqueness is accomplished in a partial order.

Comment: What is your definition of $\min_\prec B$?

Comment: The minimum of a set is unique, **provided it exists**. In your example, $\min_\prec B$ does not exist. What is your definition of minimum?

Comment: The minimum element of a partially ordered set $B$ is an element $m\in B$ such that $m\prec x$ for all $x\in B.$ Your set $B$ has no minimum element. For example, is $\{a\}$ minimum? Does $\{a\}\prec x$ hold for every $x\in B$? Let's see. $\{a\}\prec\{a,b\},$ check. $\{a\}\prec\{a\},$ check. $\{a\}\prec\{b\},$ OOPS.

Comment: The definition I am using is the following:  
$x\in B$ is called minimum or just min of $B$ if, and only if, $x$ is a lower bound for $B$.   
Definition of lower bound: $x\in A$ is called lower bound for $B$ if, and only if $x\leq b$ for each $b\in B$.

Comment: That's right, in the example I've given it doesn't work, so how I am supposed to prove the problem?

Comment: Dear @user3125470, Suppose $b_1$ and $b_2$ are minimum elements of $B$. What can you then say about them by applying the definition?

Comment: As for my understanding $b_1$ and $b_2$ are lower or equal than all elements in $B$, and $b_1 = b_2$, or if they are not the same then they can't be compared.

Comment: If $b_1$ and $b_2$ are minimum elements of $B,$ the $b_1\le b_2$ (because $b_1$ is a lower bound for $B$ and $b_2\in B$) and $b_2\le b_1$ (because $b_2$ is a lower bound for $B$ and $b_1\in B$). From $b_1\le b_2$ and $b_2\le b_1$ it follows from the antisymmetric property of the partial order that $b_1=b_2.$

Comment: This question can be closed, it was my fault misunderstanding the definition. In the example case, I thought multiple minima would exist e.g. $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$, but @bof pointed it out, no minimum is contained in the set.